# I tried to make a program that type N numbers and decide if that number is a prime . (Must use functions) I wrote this :

Tags: python, function, python-3.6, primes

```
x = int(input())
for i in range(x) :
  def isPrime(n):
    a = isPrime(int(input()))
    if n==2 or n==3: return True
    if n%2==0 or n<2: return False
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):   
      if n%i==0:
        return False    
      else :
        return True
    if False :
      print("NO")
    else :
      print("YES")
```

I tried that code but it doesn't show anything. Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You are returning inside your `for` loop, but you are not checking the return value you store in `a` in your last `if` statement.

Here is what you could do:

```
x = int(input())
for i in range(x) :
  def isPrime(n):
    a = isPrime(int(input()))
    if n==2 or n==3: return True
    if n%2==0 or n<2: return False
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):   
      if n%i==0:
        return False    
      else :
        return True
    #Here you should compare a, just checking "if false" won't do anything
    if a == False :
      print("NO")
    else :
      print("YES")
```